# getting 404 when trying to run MVC 3 RC basic app on IIS 7/5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to run an MVC3 rc new application created a simple from vs 2010 , no changes to the project , from IIS 7.5 but i'm getting 404 error.

are there some changes that are required in the web.config or IIS settings for extensionless url

I have a mvc2 running on the same IIS and tried to set the same config but I guess I'm missing something.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad I was running .net 2.0 instead of 4.0